# How to make a Pass through View which is added using window manager

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-framelayout, android-windowmanager

I have inflated a view which contains **`Constraint Layout`** as a parent layout and and a **`Frame Layout`** inside it (whose dimensions will be manupulated at runtime to be at a specific height and width).

I need add this view using a window manager to the current screen and I am successfull at it too, but the problem is it doesn't allow the views below it to be clicked through it.

Here is how my Frame Layout looks like

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_input_pointer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I also tried to make its background color to be transparent but still the views below it were not clickable untill this view over it was removed from the screen. It might be possible to do it with the help of **`WindowManager.LayoutParams`** Flags, but i was unable to find one which suits my need.

Comment: Add code snippet of how you add your view. In this case flags are critical, most notably you need [`FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE) set to ensure your view doesn't consume touch.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `view.bringToFront()` on the view below The frame layout. This is because the frame layout might stretch and cover the view below but it will not, though it might not push it down.

//NB view refers to the view below